# Remove numeric item from JsonB array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have `jsonb` value with a nested JSON array and need remove an element:

```
{"values": ["11", "22", "33"]}

jsonb_set(column_name, '{values}', ((column_name -> 'values') - '33')) -- WORKS!
```

I also have a similar `jsonb` value with **numbers**, not strings:

```
{"values": [11, 22, 33]}

jsonb_set(column_name, '{values}', ((column_name -> 'values') - 33))  -- FAILS!
```

In this case `33` is used as index of the array.

How to remove items from JSON array when those items are numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two assertions:

1. Many Postgres JSON functions and operators target the **key** in key/value pairs. **Strings** (`"abc"` or `"33"`) in JSON arrays are treated like keys without value. But numeric (`33` or `123.45`) array elements are treated as *values*.
2. There are currently three variants of the **`-`** operator. Two of them apply here. [As the recently clarified manual describes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) (currently /devel):

   > Operator
   >         Description
   >         Example(s)
   >   :---------------------
   >   `jsonb` `-` `text` → `jsonb`
   >          Deletes a key (and its value) from a JSON object, or matching string value(s) from a JSON array.
   >         `'{"a": "b", "c": "d"}'::jsonb - 'a'` → `{"c": "d"}`
   >         `'["a", "b", "c", "b"]'::jsonb - 'b'` → `["a", "c"]`
   >   ...
   >   `jsonb` `-` `integer` → `jsonb`
   >         Deletes the array element with specified index (negative integers count from the end).
   >         Throws an error if JSON value is not an array.
   >         `'["a", "b"]'::jsonb - 1` → `["a"]`

With the right operand being a [numeric literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC), Postgres [operator type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html) arrives at the later variant.

Unfortunately, we cannot use the former variant to begin with, due to assertion 1.

So we have to use a **workaround** like:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(column_name
               , '{values}'
               , (SELECT jsonb_agg(val)
                  FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.column_name -> 'values') x(val)
                  WHERE  val <> jsonb '33')
                 ) AS column_name
FROM   tbl t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=73841e0b8f2cd04ab6840268c4c97da5)*  -- with extended test case

Do **not** cast unnested elements to `integer` (like another answer suggests).

- Numeric values may not fit `integer`.
- JSON arrays (unlike Postgres arrays) can hold a mix of element types. So some array elements may be `numeric`, but others `string`, etc.
- It's more expensive to cast all array elements (on the left). Just cast the value to replace (on the right).

So this works for *any* types, not just integer (JSON numeric). Example:

```
'{"values": ["abc", "22", 33]}')
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `jsonb '33'` over `to_jsonb(33)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The first skips type resolution and coerces the string literal `'33'` to `jsonb` via associated input function. The second processes the numeric literal `33`, type resolution arrives at `integer`, so it is coerced to `integer` using the associated input function; then functions named `to_jsonb` with one argument are looked up, one is found and function type resolution accepts it as it takes `anyelement`, then the function is executed and transforms `integer` to `jsonb`. So, yes, the first one is a bit faster and less error prone. Shorter, too. (And clearer IMO.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `'33'::jsonb` does the same as `jsonb '33'`. But the latter is one character shorter. :)

Comment: I was more referring to the result, rather then efficiency.

Comment: Result is the same in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Postgres json operator `-` only supports string values, as [explained in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> operand: `-`
>
> right operand type: `text`
>
> description: Delete key/value pair or string element from left operand. Key/value pairs are matched based on their key value.

On the other hand, if you pass an integer value as right operand, Postgres considers it the *index* of the array element that needs to be removed.

An alternative option is to unnest the array with `jsonb_array_elements()` and a lateral join, filter out the unwanted value, then re-aggregate:

```
select jsonb_set(column_name, '{values}', new_values) new_column_name
from mytable t
left join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(val) new_values
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.column_name -> 'values') x(val)
    where val::int <> 33
) x on 1 = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9733bc8348fd342849db86a608ef0595)**:

```
with mytable as (select '{"values": [11, 22, 33]}'::jsonb column_name)
select jsonb_set(column_name, '{values}', new_values) new_column_name
from mytable t
left join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(val) new_values
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.column_name -> 'values') x(val)
    where val::int <> 33
) x on 1 = 1
```

```
| new_column_name      |
| :------------------- |
| {"values": [11, 22]} |
```

Answer (score 0):

### PostgreSQL 12+

Starting from this version it has powerful functionality for working with JSONB using `jsonpath` syntax. There is a great [article](https://github.com/obartunov/sqljsondoc/blob/master/jsonpath.md) written by author of this feature which describes all use cases better than official docs.

#### **jsonb_path_query_array**

Get all array items except `33`:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(
        '{"values": [11, 22, 33]}'::jsonb,
        '$.values[*] ? (@ <> 33)'
)
-- [11, 22]
```

With a combination of `jsonb_set` it gives exactly what we want:

```sql
jsonb_set(column_name, '{values}', jsonb_path_query_array(column_name, '$.values[*] ? (@ <> 33)'))
```